# Pass std::vector from managed VS test project to managed Dll

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2017, clr, vstest.console.exe

I am writing a unit test using managed VS Test project. 
I have a managed (CLI/C++) code as shown below

```
namespace ClassLibrary1 {
   public ref class Class1
        {
        std::vector<int>* vec1;
    public:
            Class1() {
                this->vec1 = new std::vector<int>();
            }
    void fillVec(std::vector<int> inp) {            
                for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = inp.begin(); it != inp.end(); ++it) {
                    this->vec1->push_back(*it);
                }
        }
}
```

I had build the above project as DLL.

In my test project I had made the code as below, referring to the above generated dll.

```
#using "ClassLibrary1.dll" as_friend
namespace UnitTestDemoProjTwo
{
[TestClass]
    public ref class UnitTest
    {
        ClassLibrary1::Class1 ^c1;
    public: 
[TestInitialize()]
        void MyTestInitialize()
        {
            c1 = gcnew ClassLibrary1::Class1;               
        }
[TestMethod]
        void TestMethod03()
        {
            std::vector<int> temp;
            temp.clear();
            temp.push_back(12);
            temp.push_back(11);
            c1->clearVec();//func in Class1 which will clear the vector
            c1->fillVec(temp);
            Assert::AreEqual(c1->retSizeOfVec(), 2);
        }
    }
}
```

I had omitted all the other include and using statement in this above code, like **using namespase System**, and **include** . 
Now when I am trying to build the project I am getting the below error

```
error C2664: 'void ClassLibrary1::Class1::fillVec(std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> > *)': 
    cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> > *'
```

I even tried **c1->fillVec(&temp);** to match the argement given in the error comments, still no luck.

Could anyone please help me out how to resolve the bottleneck?

Comment: I doubt that anybody has a real shot at guessing why the error message does not match the code.  This is a pretty typical mishap caused by the `#using` directive.  The compiler has to find that file and that does not often work out well the first time.  What you *should* do is modify the project settings to tell it where to look, but what you probably *did* do was copy the file.  That worked.  Once.

Comment: I tried adding the reference for ClassLibrary1 to UnitTestDemoProjTwo project from project->Add references; instaed of #using. Now the error is coming as **error C3767: 'ClassLibrary1::Class1::fillVec': candidate function(s) not accessible**. I think it is unable to access the managed func() through DLL, as I am passing unmanaged Containers(std::vector). need help in how to pass that vector.

Comment: Hmya, why does it have to be accessible?  Why are you testing code that no managed code could ever call?  Trouble like this is surely a big reason why the managed unit test project templates were removed from the next version of VS.

Comment: @HansPassant Actually this is a demo project, where I need to send cv::Point3i to a function. So my objective is to unit test the code which has mixture of managed and unmanaged. But trying to find is there any hack through which I can send unmanaged containers to managed dll.